# How to properly specify a Class<?> parameter using Generics

Tags: java, generics

My goal is to implement an operation that accepts class instances, but only if the concrete passed class inherits from Collection.

I get compiler warnings on my code that I cannot resolve.

```
package com.fun.with.generics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class AcceptTypedClass
{
    // Warning here on 'Collection': ... raw type, references should be parameterized.
    private static void printCollectionClass( Class<? extends Collection> c )
    {
        System.out.println( c.getName() );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // Warning here on ArrayList: ... raw type, references should be parameterized.
        Class<ArrayList> arrayList = ArrayList.class;
        printCollectionClass( arrayList );
    }
}
```

I do understand the warning message, but if I fix the warning by adding the missing type arguments like shown below, I get an error.

```
Class<ArrayList<?>> arrayList = ArrayList.class;
```

Can somebody explain this? The question is if I can write the above code so that I get no warning (and the code works)?

Comment: Have you tried `Class<? extends Collection<?>>`?  Note that further down you are passing an `ArrayList` where a `Class` is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `printCollectionClass` method to

```
private static <T extends Collection<?>> void printCollectionClass(Class<T> c) {
        System.out.println(c.getName());
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        printCollectionClass(ArrayList.class);
    }
```

Here `printCollectionClass` will accept class which inherit from collection.

Comment: Cool.  This is the solution. (But I admit: A short explanation why the compiler is now happy would help me.)

Answer (score 0):

Class is a fundamentally bad choice as a generic "type token", i.e. some means of indicating a particular type at runtime, because there is no generic type information available at runtime.

It's better to use either:

- An instance of the class (e.g. an empty list of the appropriate type) - although this merely satisfies the compiler of type safety, without providing any runtime type information.
- An actual "type token" class, like [GSON's `TypeToken`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) or [Guice's `TypeLiteral`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html).

  Notice that the Javadoc for these two classes starts with:

  > Represents a generic type T. Java doesn't yet provide a way to represent generic types, so this class does. ...

  A GSON type token is created by making an anonymous subclass of `TypeToken`:

  ```
  TypeToken<ArrayList<String>> typeToken = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {};
  ```

  The act of subclassing bakes the generic type information into the `typeToken` instance, via `typeToken.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()`.

  Note that you can't do this generically, though - you have to create the subclass with the actual classes as generic parameters, not type variables.